# Error while creating a new rails app using the "Suspenders" gem from thoughtbot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am attempting to create a new rails app using the suspenders gem from http://thoughtbot.com/community/ ... I run the command: suspenders create .... and it beings creating the new app, creates a bunch of the standard files and then get to the following errors.

"Installing mysql (2.8.1) with native extensions /Users/nelsonkeating/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:533:in `rescue in block in build_extensions': ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. (Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError)

```
    /Users/nelsonkeating/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby extconf.rb
```

checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lm... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lz... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lsocket... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lnsl... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lmygcc... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options."

I also get:

Could not find gem 'thin (>= 0)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.
    generate    cucumber:install
Could not find gem 'thin (>= 0)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.
    generate    clearance:install
Could not find gem 'thin (>= 0)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.
    generate    clearance:features
Could not find gem 'thin (>= 0)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.
      create    public/stylesheets/sass/screen.scss

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried installing the gem `thin` with `gem install thin` ?